# How to sort list in RecyclerView which is been populated through ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout

I have a fragment(say X) which contain ViewPager and TabLayout and i am passing a fragment((say Y)with a list) three times to adapter of this viewpager but every time list is sorted by some parameter.

Y fragment contain RecyclerView. And i am passing that list to the adapter of this RecyclerView.
I am able to populate all the 3 tabs with fragment.But list inside recyclerview is not sorted.Only last tab with recyclerview was comming sorted

Please help me to find shortcoming of the code.

X Fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState).inflate(R.layout.available_bus_fragment, null);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    List<Bus> departureTimeList = mBusList;
    Collections.sort(departureTimeList, new Comparator<Bus>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Bus lhs, Bus rhs) {
            return lhs.getDepartureTime().compareTo(rhs.getDepartureTime());
        }
    });
    Fragment departureFragment = new AvailableRecyclerViewFragment(departureTimeList);
    if (getArguments()!= null) {
        departureFragment.setArguments(getArguments());
    }
    adapter.addFragment(departureFragment, "Departure");

    List<Bus> durationTimeList = mBusList;
    Collections.sort(durationTimeList, new Comparator<Bus>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Bus lhs, Bus rhs) {
            return lhs.getDurationForSorting() - rhs.getDurationForSorting();
        }
    });
    Fragment durationFragment = new AvailableRecyclerViewFragment(durationTimeList);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        durationFragment.setArguments(getArguments());
    }
    adapter.addFragment(durationFragment, "Duration");
    List<Bus> priceList = mBusList;
    Collections.sort(priceList, new Comparator<Bus>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Bus lhs, Bus rhs) {
            return lhs.getFares() - rhs.getFares();
        }
    });
    Fragment priceFragment = new AvailableRecyclerViewFragment(priceList);
    if (getArguments()!= null) {
        priceFragment.setArguments(getArguments());
    }
    adapter.addFragment(priceFragment, "Fare");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    return rootView;
}
```

This is my adapter of viewpager.

```
 public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList();

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
    super(manager);
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragments.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitles.add(title);
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragments.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
}
}
```

Y fragment (AvailableRecyclerViewFragment.java)

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState).inflate(R.layout.available_list_fragment, null);

    recycler_view = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    adapter = new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), mBusList);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recycler_view.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recycler_view.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;
}
```

Adapter for Recyclerview

```
public class CustomRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomRecyclerViewAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
private List<Bus> dataList;
Context mContext;

public CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Bus> list) {
    dataList = list;
    mContext = context;
}

public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView tv_departureTime;
    public TextView tv_arrivalTime;
    public TextView tv_duration;
    public TextView tv_price;
    public TextView tv_availableSeats;
    public TextView tv_travels;
    public TextView tv_busType;

    public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        tv_departureTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_departureTime);
        tv_arrivalTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_arrivalTime);
        tv_duration = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_duration);
        tv_price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_price);
        tv_availableSeats = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_availableSeats);
        tv_travels = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_travels);
        tv_busType = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_busType);
    }
}

@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.custom_list_row, parent, false);
    final Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
    itemView.setAnimation(anim);
    return new CustomViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Bus bus = dataList.get(position);
    holder.tv_arrivalTime.setText("" + bus.getArrivalTime());

    String[] data = bus.getDuration().split(":");

    holder.tv_departureTime.setText("" + bus.getDepartureTime());
    holder.tv_duration.setText("" + data[0] + "hr " + data[1] + "min");
    if (bus.getFareList() != null) {
        String fare = "";
        for (FareDetails tempFare : bus.getFareList()) {
            fare = fare + tempFare.getTotalFare() + ("/");
        }
        holder.tv_price.setText("" + fare.substring(0, fare.length() - 1).toString());
    } else {
        holder.tv_price.setText("" + bus.getFares());
    }
    holder.tv_availableSeats.setText("" + bus.getAvailableSeats() + " seats");
    holder.tv_travels.setText(bus.getTravels());
    holder.tv_busType.setText(bus.getBusType());
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

inside of Fragment X(where your ViewPager is) call method setOnPageChangeListener:

```
   viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {


        }
    });
```

As you see inside of onPageSelected() call notifyDataSetChanged for your viewpager adapter. Then it should sort fragment that you're on.

Comment: was this answer helpful?